# LTV-3120 driver tester

Tags: mosfet-driver, tester

I am trying to build a MOSFET gate driver tester. More precisely, a tester for the [LTV-3120](https://www.tme.eu/Document/8f8451fa0680d8fdac9cefc3f38134c4/LTV-3120.pdf) driver circuit.

I have found a tester for the TLP-250 which is a similar circuit, but uses transistors instead of MOSFETs internally.

The schematic:

[image]

The way it should work is: initially the upper LED is on, when the button on the left is pressed and the optocoupler is triggered, the first LED should go off and the second one should light up.

On my test board both LEDs are on and a button push does nothing.

Did I do something wrong, or is this tester circuit invalid for the LTV-3120?

Comment: Welcome! _”transistors instead of MOSFETs”_ FYI, MOSFETs are transistors. The T stands for transistor.

Comment: yeah, badly phrased, but true... that's why i believe it should work fine...

Comment: Do you mean BJT?

Comment: It should work - with no input, the output should be low, and only the upper LED should be on. Both on indicates tri-state. What voltages do you read on the output? You might try adding a 1k pull-down resistor on the output, which might be a good idea for an actual design application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working as described. I just happened to have 5 bad ICs ;D
keep on, and thanks for confirmation!